# Area of two curves given in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Any tips how do i calculate area? Where $r = 2 +2\sin(2\theta)$ where $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$ and $r = 3$. i want to calculate area in $r = 2 +2\sin(2\theta)$ and out of $r = 3$.

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph?

Comment: yes it interesects the circle at 4 points.

Comment: And you know the formula for polar area?

Comment: yes. it is 1/2*integral of (r) but i don't uderstand  how do i exclude the area of the circle , for example if i calculate area(of the outer function) from pi/6 to pi/3 then this area also lies in the circle and out of the circle , how do i subtract area which is inside the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT....You need the $\theta$ values in the first quadrant for which $$2+2\sin2\theta=3$$ 
Use these as the limits on the integral $\int\frac 12r^2d\theta$ and subtract the sector of the circle inside

Comment: i got it , thanks :-)